# Tasks executed by executors doesn't match the total tasks

Tags: apache-spark

I am running a spark application with ~400GB data. Ask shown in the picture below, there are total 27072 tasks created by the framework, however, only 10247 tasks are executed.

So that on the Spark UI, it is shown as 10247/27072 (there is no failed tasks, just not all task get executed). Moreover, it seems the job produced the correct output even not all tasks are executed.

Can anyone help me to understand this wired behavior. For some reason, it is only happened when I process 400GB data. I run the job with a subset of the original data. I don't see such behavior.

[image]

Comment: Is it not because tasks were retried after a failure?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I didn't find any fail task from my application. Is there any page or log I should dig into?